# How to connect schedule 40 PVC conduit to an outdoor metal enclosure/panel?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

Assuming that the outdoor metal enclosure only has knockouts for connections.

If I were using flex conduit I could use a Liquidtight connector:

[image]

And if I were installing this indoors I could use a standard PVC male adapter with a locknut:

[image]

But what about for schedule 40 rigid PVC conduit outdoors? I can't find any regular PVC adapters that come with an o-ring or gasket and all the Liquidtight [product information](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Southwire-3-4-in-Liquidtight-NM-Straight-PVC-Conduit-Fitting-Connector-58133702/204755884) I can find states that they are for use with flex conduit:

> Non-metallic liquid tight connectors are made to use with type B Non-metallic liquid tight conduit.

So what gives? Surely the o-ring makes sense for outside connections. Do the Liquidtight connectors actually fit on rigid schedule 40 PVC conduit as well?

Comment: the one you are showing for schedule 40 is tapered so it wont work for nuts. Find one that is not tapered.

Comment: Are you coming in above the bottom of any busbars or other live parts in the box, or is it going into the "knockout zone" on the enclosure? (i.e. below all the busbars/live parts, where all the factory knockout locations are)

Comment: There is generally no need for or point to having a watertight seal, if you are using the standard openings on a weatherproof box. The **inside** of the conduit is defined as (and normally meets the definition) a wet location. You use the same PVC adapter you'd use indoors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You already linked a picture of the thing I use.  The second one without the locknut shown.  What's wrong with that?

You may be under a mistaken impression about the so-called watertightness of underground conduit.  That is a joke.  Underground conduit should be presumed to be 100% full of water 100% of the time. It will tend to collect water simply from condensation even if you figured out how to keep all rain out, which isn't likely.

The defense is in the choice of wires.   In other words, outdoor conduit is - surprise - outdoors!  And you can't use indoor-only wire like NM in it.

By the way, isn't your stub-up supposed to be schedule 80?  Yes I know Home Depot doesn't sell schedule 80, they don't sell a lot of stuff.

Comment: > What's wrong with that?

Haha no idea! I just assumed that the folks who design and build these things know more than I do and the Liquidtight connectors do come with o-rings so I assumed that they were there for a reason.

Comment: > By the way, isn't your stub-up supposed to be schedule 80? 

I was under the impression that schedule 40 was OK if the stub-up is secured against a building but I could certainly be wrong about that!

Answer (score 4):

Where I am we use this set up - sch. 40 PVC into a male adapter and  locknut. Not sure why you think you need the o-ring- we have never used one. If you really want one on there then grab a male adapter and most hardware stores will have a variety of o-rings to choose from.

The only thing I would add is that a bushing is required where I live inside the box (see Picture) and threaded onto the male adapter to protect the cable from any sharp edges on the male adapter.

[image]

Comment: Since electrical codes vary by country/region/city, you might want to specify "where I am" actually is.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so the consensus seems to be that there's nothing wrong with using a standard male terminal adapter for the connection given that outdoor conduit is not presumed to be 100% waterproof. That makes sense and I've already accepted the first answer but I was just looking through the [Carlon non-metallic conduit fittings catalog](https://carlonsales.com/techinfo/brochures/conduit/Conduit_Fittings_Schedule_40_and_80.pdf) and found this product:

[image: Flat Sealing Washer]

The description reads:

> Where a waterproof termination is required into any enclosure (metallic or
> non-metallic), install the neoprene washer over the threads of a terminal
> adapter before inserting into the enclosure. Use a standard locknut or
> threaded bushing to secure the assembly.

I'm not a licensed electrician but this seems like it couldn't hurt.

Comment: Yes, I ordered some last month but found it difficult to source them (in the US at least).